# ClientError: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using a Django website running on an ubuntu EC2 instance with S3 for hosting my static and media. When I try to upload an image file to a model I receive the following.

"An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

I have an iam user with AmazonS3FullAccess and I copy and pasted the correct Access key into my settings.py file. I am able to run collectstatic and access the buckets through the terminal, and I even have my static served correctly on my website, but no user can upload images or files. I'v run and rerun aws configure, but still no luck.

Here is the relevant code from my utils.py and settings.py:

utils.py

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
```

settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'access_key'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret_key'

S3_REGION_NAME ='aws_region'


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'my-project.utils.MediaStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-project-bucket'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'my-project.utils.StaticStorage'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '//%s.s3-aws_region.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

MEDIA_URL = AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN + 'media/'
STATIC_URL = AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN + 'static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

my /.aws/config and credentials file also have the same copy and pasted Id and Keys.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just to clarify, where do you have your keys defined.  In `settings.py` or `utils.py`?

Comment: Can you run `aws configure list` to check if all the keys set in the environment are identical. It could be possible that some wrong configuration is overriding all correct ones.

Comment: I have checked all the details with my working config and the only difference is MEDIA_ROOT. It should be just "media/". Can you check it?

Comment: Why not using 
`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`

Comment: @mootmoot because location is different for storing static and media files

Comment: @franklinsijo, when I run aws configure list, it returns the last four digits of my access id and secrety key as my only credentials.

Comment: @Alexander Tyapkov I tried commenting out the line in MEDIA_ROOT, but I saw no change.

Comment: @Jesse try not to comment it out, but change it to MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'

Comment: *The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records* means exactly what it says. Usually, it's a copypaste error, but there's one other common cause... Confirm your access key id begins with `AKIA` and not `ASIA`?

Comment: @Alexander Tyapkov I just tried that change, and also as '/media/' but neither made a difference

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I thought so too, but I've been copy and pasting repeatedly to no avail. But just to see if I am crazy here are my Access Keys:  From the IAM account: 'AKIAKU45PIMXIHWY3RQQ'; from settings.py: 'AKIAKU45PIMXIHWY3RQQ', and from the .aws/config file: 'AKIAKU45PIMXIHWY3RQQ'. If I am missing something please let me know. As I mentioned above I can still run collectstatic, which is just a different folder in the same bucket.

Comment: I believe the accesskeyid is checked very early, so the split behavior is not at all intuitive since even an object or bucket that's world-readable should still throw the error.  I'm quite familiar with the raw API but not boto3... can you debug the actual http request and see what's going out on the wire?  Also the response should have some more useful XML, hiding somewhere, describing specifically what access key the system is rejecting.  The SDKs have a bad habit of "helpfully" not showing the entire error response.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I tried looking through the http request, but unfortunately I don't think I was able to figure out how to view what access key was being sent out. I am still somewhat new to developing, so any further guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you found the HTTP request (not some kind of request object but the actual request headers and body), or the response, edit them into the question.  The access key id should be readily apparent.